# Wait for data from one observable to be used later

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have the following code in an angular component:

```
@Component({...})
export class ComponentOne implements OnDestroy, OnChanges {

  readonly myBehaviourSub = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<MY_CUSTOM_INTERFACE>>(NEVER);

  constructor(private readonly myService: MyService){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.myBehaviourSub.next(
      this.myService.fetchSomeData(alpha, beta, gamma)// 'fetchSomeData' returns an observable with type MY_CUSTOM_INTERFACE
        .pipe(
          shareReplay({refCount: true, bufferSize: 1})
         )
    );
      
  }

}
```

and *MyService* is something like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyService {

  fetchSomeData(alpha, beta, gamma) : Observable<MY_CUSTOM_INTERFACE> {
     ...
     return obs<MY_CUSTOM_INTERFACE>;
  }

  fetchNewValuesForAlpha() : Observable<ALPHA_INTERFACE> {
     ...
     return obs<ALPHA_INTERFACE>
  }

}
```

I want to get new values of "alpha" by calling "fetchNewValuesForAlpha" before passing "alpha" to "fetchSomeData".

This is what I did:

```
@Component({...})
export class ComponentOne implements OnDestroy, OnChanges {

  readonly myBehaviourSub = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<MY_CUSTOM_INTERFACE>>(NEVER);

  constructor(private readonly myService: MyService){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.myBehaviourSub.next(
      this.myService.fetchNewValuesForAlpha()
        .pipe(
          switchMap(response => response.newValue))
        .subscribe(
          (newAlpha) => this.myService.fetchSomeData(newAlpha, beta, gamma)
          .pipe(shareReplay({refCount: true, bufferSize: 1})
         ); 
     );
   }

}
```

The problem is that "fetchNewValuesForAlpha" returns an observable. I tried using switchMap to accomplish this, however, I am getting the following error:

> Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<MY_CUSTOM_INTERFACE>'

Answer (score 0):

You're subscribing already in the ngOnChanges and thus returning a subscription. The wanted effect is more like the code below. The switchMap is now at the right point for getting the fetchSomeData-data.

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.myBehaviourSub.next(
      this.myService.fetchNewValuesForAlpha()
        .pipe(
          map(response => response.newValue),
          switchMap(newAlpha=>this.myService.fetchSomeData(newAlpha,beta, gamma)
           .pipe(
             shareReplay({refCount: true, bufferSize: 1})
             ) 
          )
        )
     )
  }
```